# TypeScript - Erro TS1206 Decorators are not valid here

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso muito de um help, não consigo de jeito nenhum rodar minha app FRONT END, um projeto da empresa, quando dou um npm start em meu terminal no visual code, um bendito erro persiste, que é no @Component dizendo Error TS1206 Decorators are not valid here. Segue abaixo o código, estou iniciando no TYPESCRIPT e ANGULAR 6.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ServicesMonitoring',
  templateUrl: './ServicesMonitoring.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ServicesMonitoring.component.scss']
})

export interface LineBusiness {
  value: number;
  viewValue: string;
}

export class SelectLineBusiness {
  business: LineBusiness[] = [
    {value: 0, viewValue: 'Carro'},
    {value: 1, viewValue: 'Carga'},
    {value: 2, viewValue: 'Carro reserva'},
    {value: 2, viewValue: 'RE'}
  ];
}

export class ServicesMonitoringComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

O trecho é em @Component, na minha estrutura de pasta, conforme desenho abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para resolver isso? E rodar minha aplicação? Pois o arquivo ServicesMonitoring.component.scss esta vazio, isso tem a ver com o problema?

Obrigado

Comment: Tenta atualizar seu node e npm pras versões mais recentes.

Answer (score 4):

A anotação de `@component` tem que estar em cima da class do seu componente e não em cima de uma interface de modelo:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ServicesMonitoring',
  templateUrl: './ServicesMonitoring.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ServicesMonitoring.component.scss']
})
export class ServicesMonitoringComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```